# how to check the last entry in a while loop and insert row after the last row in a table in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Is it possible to check each row on 'while' loop whether it's the last row or not, without knowing number of rows first?

Comment: You must know what the last row is. Is it an array then the last item is count($array)-1. If it is a database row, fetch all rows into an array and check like above.

Comment: yes its coming from db but i am arranging it in the form of array

Comment: With databases you usually have some function like [mysqli_num-rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) in MySQL (telling you how many results there are). Otherwise, do it like @HasseBjörk mentionned. For a better answer, we'd need some code.

Comment: I am not able to copy all the code here

Comment: <?php
$arr = array();
$project = array();
$current_test_phase = array();
$plan_start_date = array();
$rev_start_date = array();
$plan_end_date = array();
$rev_end_date = array();
$test_count = array();
$exec_percent = array();
$test_exec_count = array();
$pass_rate_percent = array();
$pass_rate = array();
$blocked_test_case = array();
$comment = array();
$admin_comments = array();

Comment: while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


$row['admin_comment']='';
array_push($project, $row['project']);
array_push($current_test_phase, $row['current_test_phase']);
array_push($plan_start_date, $row['plan_start_date']);
array_push($rev_start_date, $row['rev_start_date']);
array_push($plan_end_date, $row['plan_end_date']);
array_push($rev_end_date, $row['rev_end_date']);
array_push($test_count, $row['test_count']);
array_push($exec_percent, $row['exec_percent']);
array_push($test_exec_count, $row['test_exec_count']);
array_push($pass_rate_percent, $row['pass_rate_percent']);

Comment: array_push($pass_rate, $row['pass_rate']);
array_push($blocked_test_case, $row['Blocked_test_case']);
array_push($comment, $row['comment']);
array_push($admin_comments, $row['admin_comment']);

 if (!isset($arr[$row['project']])) {
                $arr[$row['project']]['rowspan'] = 0;
            }
            $arr[$row['project']]['printed'] = 'no';
            $arr[$row['project']]['rowspan'] += 1;
            }

for($i=0; $i < sizeof($current_test_phase); $i++) {
            $empName = $project[$i];
            echo "<tr>";
            $number_of_rows = $arr[$empName]['rowspan'];

Comment: if ($arr[$empName]['printed'] == 'no') {
                echo "<td id='all_projects' rowspan='".$number_of_rows."'>".$empName."</td>";
                $arr[$empName]['printed'] = 'yes';
                $project_name = $empName;
                //echo $project_name;

            }
            echo "<td>".$current_test_phase[$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$plan_start_date[$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$rev_start_date[$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$plan_end_date[$i]."</td>";

Comment: echo "<td>".$rev_end_date[$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$test_count[$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$exec_percent[$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$test_exec_count[$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$pass_rate_percent[$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$pass_rate[$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$blocked_test_case[$i]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$comment[$i]."</td>";
            
            //echo "<td colspan='5'>".$comment[$i]."</td>";
            // echo "<td>".$admin_comments[$i]."</td>";
            
        }

Comment: please edit your post and place the code there instead :(

Answer (score 0):

you can use end function to move the pointer to last array index like this:

```
$your_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
end($your_array);         
$last_key = key($your_array);
```

by this you have the last key of your array, if you want to know the last row in while loop you can compare key in while loop by your last key like this:

```
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($your_array) )
{
    if($key==$last_key) {
    //write your code here
    }
}
```